# How to Convert Columns to rows in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have data like below and am trying to convert columns to rows in Oracle. But I am getting "Pivot is a Invalid Identifier".

Sample Source Data:

```
DEPTNO DEPTNAME SAL 
10     HR       1000
10    ACCOUNTS  2000
20     HR       3000
20    ACCOUNTS  4000
10    CLERK     5000
```

Expected Output:

```
DEPTNO  HR   ACCOUNTS CLERK
10     1000   2000     5000
20     3000   4000
```

I tried to run below query but ended with error. Please help me on this.

```
select *
from   table( pivot(' select deptno
                      ,      job
                      ,      SAL
                      from   emp
                      group
                      by     deptno
                      ,      job
                    ')
            )
```

Error:

> PIVOT is a invalid modifier.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select deptno,
       sum(case when deptname = 'HR' then salary end) as hr,
       sum(case when deptname = 'ACCOUNTS' then salary end) as accounts,
       sum(case when deptname = 'CLERK' then salary end) as clerk
from t
group by deptno;
```

Comment: In my production data, we have around 400 values in DEPTNAME, Is there any way to pick up values dynamically instead of hard coded values. Thanks for your support In advance.

Comment: @Sudha. . . I would suggest that you construct the query using a spreadsheet.